# Appending values to a google sheet

Tags: java, google-sheets-api

What am i doing wrong? I wanna append values to a sheet:

```
    String valueInputOption = "USER_ENTERED";
    String range = "1:1";
    String ranges = "Student!2:2";

    ValueRange response = service.spreadsheets().values()
            .get(spreadsheetId, range)
            .execute();

    AppendValuesResponse appendValuesResponse = service.spreadsheets()
            .values()
            .append(spreadsheetId, ranges, response)
            .setValueInputOption(valueInputOption)
            .execute();
```

but i get exception:

```
{
 "code" : 400,
 "errors" : [ {
 "domain" : "global",
 "message" : "Request range[Student!2:2] does not match value's 
  range[Student!A1:Z1]",
 "reason" : "badRequest"
} ],
"message" : "Request range[Student!2:2] does not match value's 
range[Student!A1:Z1]",
"status" : "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
}
```

i dont know why my range is wrong...

Comment: I've never used that API before, but judging by the error codes its looking for a range in the format `String ranges = "Student!A2:B2";`

Comment: Anyway it calls the exception. About range(2:2) it means second row. I think it must be correctly but i dont know why that is wrong

Answer (score 0):

Check the [Reading a single range](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values#reading_a_single_range) and [Appending values](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values#appending_values) and it should demonstrate how to use the API properly. It seems the error stems from using 2 different ranges. Try to use only one to get rid of this error and work your way from there.